# Bootstrap nav menu has line breaks in IE/Edge

Tags: css, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap-3, microsoft-edge

Using Bootstrap v3.3.7 I have a menu with a bullet point between each item. It works fine on Chrome/Firefox/Safari/Opera on Win 10/Mac/iPad/Android (where browser/platform compatable).

However, on  IE 11 and Edge 42 on Win 10, as you resize the browser, one of the bullets will take up a line on it's own, see grab.

HTML/CSS below also.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/design/iebull.css?v=4">
<script src="/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script defer src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>



<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
     <div class='centered_content'>

        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">

            <ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
                    <li><a href='#'>Navigation item here</a></li> 
                    <li><i>&bull;</i></li> <li><a href='#'>Navigation item </a></li> 
                    <li><i>&bull;</i></li> <li><a href='#'>Navigation item 1</a></li> 
                    <li><i>&bull;</i></li> <li><a href='#'>Navigation item 12</a></li> 
                    <li><i>&bull;</i></li> <li><a href='#'>Navigation item 123</a></li> 
                    <li><i>&bull;</i></li> <li><a href='#'>Navigation item 1234</a></li> 
                    <li><i>&bull;</i></li> <li><a href='#'>Navigation item 12345</a></li> 
                    <li><i>&bull;</i></li> <li><a href='#'>Navigation item 123456</a></li> 
                    <li><i>&bull;</i></li> <li><a href='#'>Navigation item 1234567</a></li> 
                    <li><i>&bull;</i></li> <li><a href='#'>Navigation item 12345678</a></li> 
                    <li><i>&bull;</i></li> <li><a href='#'>Navigation item 123456789</a></li> 
                    <li><i>&bull;</i></li> <li><a href='#'>Navigation item here</a></li> 
                    <li><i>&bull;</i></li> <li><a href='#'>Navigation item here</a></li> 
                    <li><i>&bull;</i></li> <li><a href='#'>Navigation item here</a></li> 
                    <li><i>&bull;</i></li> <li><a href='#'>Navigation item here</a></li> 
                    <li><i>&bull;</i></li> <li><a href='#'>Navigation item here</a></li> 
            </ul>

          </div>
        </div>

    </div>  <!--/ centered_content -->
   </nav>


</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-padding-start: 0;
}




.centered_content {
  max-width:1100px; 
  margin: auto;
}




.navbar-default {
    background-color: #cc0000;
    border-color: #e7e7e7;
}



.navbar {
    min-height: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}


.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  font-size: 19px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding:10px;
  text-align: left;
}



.nav>li>a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 8px;
}


.nav>li>i {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 1px 1px;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-style: normal;
    color: #e0c062;
}



/* thought it may be display: block; on the above two, but removing it did not fix */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

keep the `i` tag inside `a` tag like below

```
<li><a href='#'><i>&bull;</i> Navigation item </a></li>
```

And the gap you can adjust with css

Comment: Thanks! Am home now so will try it tomorrow.

Comment: It worked many thanks. I also used a Font Awesome circle instead of the &bull; as I was having problems getting it aligned within the link tag.